Can WiX toolset be included in a source repo?
Visual Studio 2022 - C# - WiX toolset v3.11
I’m interested in including the wix toolset installation files in my solution so that anyone who pulls the repo already has wix available for use. I have included the files in a solution folder and pathed to that folder for things like calling heat.exe for harvesting. However when building my wix setup project, executables like Candle.exe and Light.exe are being called under the hood and pathing to them in the original installation folder outside of my solution even though those same files are in the solution.
How can I ensure visual studio looks in my solution folder for the wix exe’s that need to be used. Is there a way to achieve this at a solution level as there are many projects in this solution leveraging WiX so it would be nice to set it up in one place for all projects to pick up.
